# MongoDb mongostat monoitoring for a particular database

Tags: mongodb

My MongoDB server has different Databases.

I need to get the stats for a particular MongoDB database.

For instance, i need something like this :

mongostat -h ip address database name

Can anyone let me know if this is possible ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `mongostat` utility reports statistics for the whole instance (all databases) and does not get anymore specific than that (besides reporting the database with the highest lock since 2.2)

The [`mongotop`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongotop/) utility will give you per-database (and collection) reporting but only for a limited amount of information (time spent, [locks](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongotop/#cmdoption--locks))

Combining the two will give you a decent idea of what your busiest collections/databases may be.

Beyond that, MMS will give you reporting on a per-database basis as long as the [database specific stats are enabled](https://docs.mms.mongodb.com/faq/#how-does-mms-gather-database-statistics).